# Does the hashrate/hash power represent the number of single or double sha256 operations that can be done per second?

Tags: mining-theory, hashpower, sha256

When we state that someone has, for example, a hashrate of 240 H/s, does it imply the capability to perform 240 SHA256 hash operations (equivalent to 120 double-SHA256 operations) or 240 double-SHA256 operations? In other words, does the term "hashrate" or "hash power" refer to the number of single SHA256 hash operations or the number of double SHA256 operations that someone can execute in one second?

Comment: Other very very similar question: [How is hash rate of mining hardware calculated](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/28227/13866) and [Bitcoin Performance: What does Hashes/Second Mean?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/25013/13866)